# Clarification for proof in section 8, example 6 in Elementary Analysis (2nd ed.) by Ross

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I was wondering about the last line of equations and inequalities in the following excerpt from Ross' *Elementary Analysis*:

[image: page 43 from Ross]

It seems to me that the last inequality, i.e. $|{s - s_n}|+|s_n|<\frac{|s|}{2}+\frac{|s|}{2}$, contradicts (1) just above it.

I found an errata for the book, but this is not mentioned. Maybe something escapes me. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author uses the last inequality to prove $(1)$. The logic is as follows.

Assume that $(1)$ does not hold, then there exists $n_0>N$ such that $|s_{n_0}|<\frac{|s|}2$. For this $n_0$, since $n_0>N$, we have $|s_{n_0}-s|<\frac{|s|}2$, hence
$$|s|=|s-s_{n_0}+s_{n_0}|\leq |s-s_{n_0}|+|s_{n_0}|<\frac{|s|}2+\frac{|s|}2=|s|,$$
so we deduce that $|s|<|s|$, which is absurd. Therefore $(1)$ holds.

Answer (score 3):

Can you see that "since **otherwise**..." which resorts to the proof of contradiction, that is, if (1) does not hold, then we have the last inequality, which is absurd

Comment: Boy, is my face red. Shoddy reading on my part!